# WSO2 ESB Issue with Tibco EMS 8.0 integration

Tags: wso2, esb, tibco-ems, tibco-business-works

I tried to enable JMS transport on WSO2 ESB with Tibco EMS.

With Tibco BW 6.3.0 - copied the below client jars to `{wso2esb-4.8.0}\repository\components\lib`

`tibjms.jar, jms.jar`   - working without any issues.

With Tibco EMS 8.0 -copied the below client jars to `{wso2esb-4.8.0}\repository\components\lib`

`tibjms.jar, jms-2.0.jar` - Results exception as ClassNotFound.

As per WSO2 ESB documentation, it supports only JMS 1.1 and 1.0.2b spec. So tried with Combination of jars.

https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/JMS+Transport#JMSTransport-JMSConnectionFactoryParameters

i.e. Jms.jar from Tibco-6.3.0 and tibjms.jar from Tibco 8.0 - Results same exception as ClassNotFound. Below is the exception Stack trace.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSContext
>           at com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsContext$Messenger.(TibjmsContext.java:316)
>           at com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsContext.lookup(TibjmsContext.java:651)
>           at com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsContext.lookup(TibjmsContext.java:491)
>           at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSUtils.lookup(JMSUtils.java:583)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactory.(JMSConnectionFactory.java:93)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactoryManager.loadConnectionFactoryDefinitions(JMSConnectionFactoryManager.java:58)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactoryManager.(JMSConnectionFactoryManager.java:45)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.init(JMSSender.java:67)
>           at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.initTransportSenders(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:300)
>           at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.init(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:231)
>           at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:93)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonConfigurationContextFactory.createNewConfigurationContext(CarbonConfigurationContextFactory.java:65)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:398)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:219)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:77)

## Trasport Configuration in axis2.xml

```
<transportReceiver class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener" name="jms">
  <parameter locked="false" name="ESB-POC-CF-00">
  <parameter locked="false" name="java.naming.factory.initial">com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory</parameter>
  <parameter locked="false" name="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://127.0.0.1:7222</parameter>
  <parameter locked="false" name="java.naming.security.principal">admin</parameter>
  <parameter locked="false" name="java.naming.security.credentials"/>
  <parameter locked="false" name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName">ESB-POC-CF-00</parameter>
  <parameter locked="false" name="transport.jms.JMSSpecVersion">1.1</parameter>
  <parameter locked="false" name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType">queue</parameter>
  <parameter locked="false" name="transport.jms.UserName">xprk119</parameter>
  <parameter locked="false" name="transport.jms.Password">esb119</parameter>
  </parameter>
```

As Tibco 8.0 support backward compatibility. we are interested to integrate esb with tibco 8.0 version. Please let me know the way to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You have to include also jms-2.0.jar that comes in EMS 8.0 distribution. That is where your missing class is.

HTH.

Comment: Hi Ramon, I have copied the Tibjms.jar, jms-2.0.jar that came with tibco ems 8.0 but Results same exception as ClassNotFound. Below is the exception Stack trace.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSContext .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with WebSphere and Tibco 8. Adding both jars - tibjms.jar and ms-2.0.jar to classpath solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Mahesh.

I had a similar issue some days ago. I think the problem is related with OSGi and the classloaders loading order. I had solved it using the OSGi plugins that comes with EMS 8.2 (I did not know if also with previous 8.x), and referencing them from the plugins that need them.